# error appears out of blue in console

Tags: javascript

I am receiving an error in my error console which states: arguments array passed to Function.prototype.apply is too large and the file it is in is: resource://ct2504091/BackStage.jsm. Does anyone know why this error suddenly appears out of the complete blue?

Below is the code from the view source of where the error is appearing in:

```
var postBytes = stream.readByteArray(stream.available());
poststr = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, postBytes);
```

Comment: What's in / how big is the arguments array you're passing to `apply()`? `console.log()` it if unsure.

Comment: I am only trying to upload a 4 second audio mp3 file, 3.91mb

Comment: Confused... can you edit the question to show us some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Google search for "javascript BackStage.jsm" reveals: You seem to have installed a "Bibirmer for Firefox Plugin" that interfers with you code. Try uninstalling it.

Comment: How do you uninstall something from firefox? Where do I find bibrimer from?

Comment: Extras -> Addons -> Bibirmer -> uninstall. Hope my guess is right :-)

Comment: It doesn't find bibrimer when I try to search it under add ons?

Comment: I'm lost then, sorry for the unhelpful answer :-/